# What is the maximum amount of different bacteria in the drinking water in Europe?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology

I am looking for a statistical amounts which are allowed.
Some students say it is 0 for all bacteria, which I think is false.
I found [this USA source](http://water.epa.gov/drink/contaminants/).

I found there

- Total Coliforms (including fecal coliform and E. Coli) mg/l. No more than 5.0% samples total coliform-positive (TC-positive) in a month.
- Giardia lamblia: 99.9% removal/inactivation.

**What is the right place to look for such information?**

Comment: According to a text I'll reference later, humans face larger risk with microbial contaminants that chemical ones. This is the reason why most water quality standards and guidelines (including who) recommend (or allow) 0 counts per 100 ml for bacterial indicators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your colleages are right: There should be no coliforms in drinking water in Europe following the [Council Directive 80/777/EEC](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX:31980L0777:EN:HTML).
This PDF from the [Northern Ireland Environment Agency](http://www.coralenvironmental.com/wp-content/uploads/European-and-National-Drinking-Water-Quality-Standards.pdf) (which follows the directice mentioned above) shows this a bit nicer.
It makes sense, since coliforms are a sign of mixing sewage and fresh water. Nothing you want to have happening.

This is the relevant table from the linked PDF:

[image]